# How to add square braces around subarray data inside of a json encoded string?

Tags: php, json

When trying to access an API the JSON array must be parsed like this

```
{"item":[{"id":"123456", "name":"adam"}]}
```

But when i'm doing the following code

```
$data = array("item" => array("id" => "123456", "name" => "adam"));
echo json_encode($data);
```

it returns the json array without squared brackets as follows

```
{"item":{"id":"123456","name":"adam"}}
```

I've spent hours trying to figure out how to fix this and just can't think of a solution

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You need to wrap things in another `array`:

```
$data = array("item" => array(array("id" => "123456", "name" => "adam")));
```

This will be more understandable if we use the equivalent PHP 5.4 array syntax:

```
$data = [ "item" => [ ["id" => "123456", "name" => "adam"] ] ];
```

Compare this with the JSON:

```
        { "item":   [ {"id":"123456", "name":"adam"      } ] }
```

The only thing to explain is why one of the PHP arrays remains an array `[]` in JSON while the other two get converted to an object `{}`. But the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) already does so:

> When encoding an array, if the keys are not a continuous numeric
>   sequence starting from 0, all keys are encoded as strings, and
>   specified explicitly for each key-value pair.

Comment: When using that code as provided it's placing the squared brackets outside everything instead of inside `item` ?

Comment: @CurtisCrewe: Sorry, typo. Fixed now.

Answer (score 9):

Before reading this post, I had this:

`echo json_encode($data);`

After reading this post:

```
echo json_encode(array($data));
```

Brackets appeared at the start and end of the JSON object.

Comment: Useful, but if you want the brackets IN the data arrays, just use something like this: `$MyArray = array( "something" => [array("foo" => "bar")] );`

Answer (score 3):

It become handy when using this way, so you can add more items on the array

```
$val = array();
$val["id"]="123456";
$val["name"]="adam";

$data = array();
$data["item"][]=$val;

echo json_encode($data);
```

And it will ouput below:

```
{"item":[{"id":"123456", "name":"adam"}]}
```