# Square API Create Item working code now returning an error

Tags: php, curl, square-connect

After creating about 1000 inventory items with code, Square suddenly started returning an error.

The error returned was:

```
{"type":"bad_request","message":"'name' is required"}
```

Example code:

```
$postData = array(
  'id' => 'test_1433281486',
  'name' => 'test',
  'description' => 'test',
  'variations' => array(
    'id' => 'test_v1433281486',
    'name' => 'Regular',
    'price_money' => array(
      'currency_code' => 'USD',
      'amount' => '19800',
    ),
  ),
);
$json = json_encode($postData);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token, 'Content-Type: application/json', 'Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me/items");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
$json = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Here is the json_encoded string:

```
{
  "id":"test_1433281486",
  "name":"test",
  "description":"test",
  "variations": {
    "id":"test_v1433281486",
    "name":"Regular",
    "price_money": {
      "currency_code":"USD",
      "amount":"19800"
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried everything I know to do a simple Create Item with code now, but it no longer works.  Always returns the message "name" is required.  My code to update images, fees, categories etc still works perfectly - just can't create.

I still have 100's of new inventory items to add, so getting this to work is imperative to business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variations needs to be passed in as an array. Here is how the JSON should look:

```
{
  "id":"test_1433281486",
  "name":"test",
  "description":"test",
  "variations": [{
    "id":"test_v1433281486",
    "name":"Regular",
    "price_money": {
      "currency_code":"USD",
      "amount":"19800"
    }
  }]
}
```

Thanks for the report! We will update our error messaging to send the proper message if variations is not passed in as an array.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not sure why my code worked for the last couple of months, unless you recently did a code change.

Comment: [Here's the real solution / explanation to my (and other PHP developers) problem.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559735/no-square-bracket-json-array).  !!! So other platform developers - beware, Square now needs brackets in your JSON code.

Answer (score 1):

This is for all the PHP developers.  Here is an updated Create Item PHP array that is compatible with Square.  Notice the nested "variations" arrays.

Square now (6/15) requires brackets in JSON arrays - PHP json_encode() does not produce them unless you add nested arrays.

```
$postData = array(
  'id' => 'test_1433281487',
  'name' => 'test2',
  'description' => 'test2',
  'variations' => array(array(
    'id' => 'test_v1433281487',
    'name' => 'Regular',
    'price_money' => array(
      'currency_code' => 'USD',
      'amount' => '19800',
    ),
  )),
);
$json = json_encode($postData);
```

[Here's another example of JSON brackets in PHP.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559735/no-square-bracket-json-array)

[Here is the PHP json_encode() documentation.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)