# place form data in multiples array and save in json format

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

I have a form with 3 pages and each page have different fields
in my controller i am able to make data in json format which is as

**controller code**

```
$input = $request->all();
        unset($input['_token']);
        unset($input['submit']);
        $form_attributes = json_encode($input);
        dd($form_attributes);
```

**Output is as**

```
    "{"name":"test","student":"yes","email":"test.student@gmail.com","format":"auto",
"lists":["1,2"],"class_lists":["2,5"],"status":"1"}"
```

I not show full form so that it will easy to understand with small data

I want to make above out put as

> its array should save as one main array Student then page1 array page2 array and then page3 array

it should be as

```
 "Student":[{"arraypage1":[{"name":"test","student":"yes","email":"student@gmail.com"}],
    "arraypage2":[{"format":"auto","lists":["1,2"]}],
    "arraypage3":[{"class_lists":["2,5"],"status":"1"}]]"
```

Please help me to encode this data in above format 
Thanks

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: laravel version 5.3

Comment: Just FYI, but you can do `$request->except('_token', 'submit')` instead of using `unset()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily build up an associative array in your desired format, then `json_encode()` it:

```
$formattedOutput = Array(
    'student' => Array(
        'arraypage1' => Array(
            'name' => $input['name'],
            'student' => $input['student'],
            'email' => $input['email']
        ),
        'arraypage2' => Array(
            'format' => $input['format'],
            'lists' => $input['lists']
        ),
        'arraypage3' => Array(
            'class_lists' => $input['class_lists'],
            'status' => $input['status']
        )
    )
);

$form_attributes = json_encode($formattedOutput);
```

The exact key names may differ, but you should get the idea.

**UPDATE:**
To get the square brackets, you can wrap with additional `Array()`:

```
$formattedOutput = Array(
    'student' => Array(
        Array('arraypage1' =>
            Array(
                Array(
                    'name' => $input['name'],
                    'student' => $input['student'],
                    'email' => $input['email']
                )
            )
        ),
        Array('arraypage2' =>
            Array(
                Array(
                    'format' => $input['format'],
                    'lists' => $input['lists']
                )
            )
        ),
        Array('arraypage3' =>
            Array(
                Array(
                    'class_lists' => $input['class_lists'],
                    'status' => $input['status']
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

see this post for more details: [no square bracket json array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559735/no-square-bracket-json-array)

Comment: sir its looks fine but why square brackets [ ] missed out

Comment: i test for 2 arrays its as `"{"student":{"arraypage1":{"form_name":"test","double_optin":"on"},"arraypage2":{"thanks_email":"on","email":"dfsd"}}}"`  but its should be as `"{"student":[{"arraypage1":[{"form_name":"test","double_optin":"on"}],"arraypage2":[{"thanks_email":"on","email":"dfsd"}]}]}"`

Comment: To get the square brackets, you need to wrap with another `Array()`.  I'll update the answer.