# Encode PHP array with non-numeric keys to JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this PHP array:

```
$a = array(
  "french"=>"bonjour",
  "italian"=>"buongiorno",
  "spanish"=>"buenos dias"
);
```

But when I do `echo json_encode($a);`, I get:

```
{
   "french": "bonjour",
   "italian": "buongiorno",
   "spanish": "buenos dias"
}
```

i.e. a JSON object, but I want a JSON array, at the expense of preserving the string keys, like that :

```
[
   "bonjour",
   "buongiorno",
   "buenos dias"
]
```

How should I do it?

Comment: There is no thing like a "JSON object" or "JSON array". [JSON](http://json.org) is a text representation of a data structure (usually an object or an array). When it is decoded a data structure similar to the one used to create it is obtained.

Comment: I understand, but I mean I want `[ ]` brackets and not `{ }`.

Comment: @axiac, there are things called objects and arrays in JSON, so your statement is a bit misleading. Care to clarify?

Comment: What is the exact content of the JSON output that you want, @JacopoStanchi? Also, think about what the according PHP representation would be!

Comment: What's your expected result?

Comment: @k0pernikus I edited my post.

Comment: What you provide in that edit isn't JSON. However, take a look at dave's answer below, it seems to be pretty close.

Comment: This may help answer your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559735/no-square-bracket-json-array

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Edited again. In fact, thank you all for your answers but I'm just waiting the remaining time to validate dave answer.

Comment: This could also help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844223/how-do-i-json-encode-keys-from-php-array

Comment: Hello, use [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `array_values`:

```
echo json_encode(array_values($a));
```

Answer (score 1):

Php arrays are not "arrays" in the strict sense (collection of string/object/numbers/etc, identified through a numeric index), but are associative arrays. Also know as dictionaries or hash maps. They are for key-value storage.

JSON does not support dictionaries as a type, and hence `json_encode` transforms these to a json object by design, as objects are supported.

Using [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), you can determine by the second parameter if you want a hash map (php array) or an object back:

```
$a = array(
     "french" => "bonjour",
     "italian" => "buongiorno",
     "spanish" => "buenos dias"
);

$json = json_encode($a);

$object = json_decode($json, false); // this is the default behavior
$array = json_decode($json, true);

var_dump($object); // the object
var_dump($array); // same as the starting array
```

The object will be:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
  ["french"]=>
  string(7) "bonjour"
  ["italian"]=>
  string(10) "buongiorno"
  ["spanish"]=>
  string(11) "buenos dias"
}
```

And the array will be:

```
array(3) {
  ["french"]=>
  string(7) "bonjour"
  ["italian"]=>
  string(10) "buongiorno"
  ["spanish"]=>
  string(11) "buenos dias"
}
```

Comment: Hashing is irrelevant, as it's rather an implementation detail. The term you mean is dictionary, I would say. The distinction in PHP is whether the PHP array has zero-based numeric keys (is thus a "normal" array) or not. The former is encoded as JSON array, the latter as JSON object.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt The child has different names yet all mean the same thing. My main point is that JSON was never intended to represent php's associative arrays.