# Mailchimp API "Marketing permission ID '' does not exist." while passing valid id

Tags: mailchimp

I use the Mailchimp API to first get the marketing_permission_id for my list. The response looks like this

> [marketing_permission_id] => f878932739

This value is then used in a second api call to update the settings for a specific user. However, I get the error:

> string(227)
>   "{"type":"http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/","title":"Bad
>   Request","status":400,"detail":"Marketing permission ID '' does not
>   exist.", [...]

I double checked the data that is being send in the second call and it has the correct marketing_permission_id in there:

```
{"marketing_permissions":{"marketing_permission_id":"f878932739","enabled":true}}
```

I followed the format from https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#%20.

I don't understand what's going wrong. Hopefully someone here does.. :)

Comment: Just a guess: marketing_permissions' type is `Array`, you have an `Object`.

Comment: Ah yes, awesome! I was using json_encode, but that gave me

{"marketing_permissions":{"marketing_permission_id":"f878932739","enabled":true}} 

instead of the required

{"marketing_permissions": [{"marketing_permission_id": "f878932739", "enabled": true}]}

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Just leaving this for future reference - there're not many hints on google for mailchimp API with marketing permissions...
This is the basic function i use for adding a contact to a list.

```html
function syncMailchimp($userdata,
    $apiKey, $listId)
{
    
    $dataCenter = substr($apiKey,
        strpos($apiKey, '-') +
        1);
    $url = 'https://'.$dataCenter.
    '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/'
    .$listId.
    '/members/';

// This is the interesting part //

    $json = json_encode([
      'email_address' => $userdata[
            'email'],
      'status' => $userdata['status'], // "subscribed","unsubscribed","cleaned","pending"
      'merge_fields' => [
        'FNAME' => $userdata[
                'firstname'
                ],
        'LNAME' => $userdata['lastname']
      ],
       'tags' => [
        'added'
       ],
// How to build the Array -->
       'marketing_permissions' =>
       array(
            0 =>
            array(
                'marketing_permission_id' =>
                '1e5142bbce',
                'enabled' =>
                true,
            ),
         ),
    ]);

    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch,
        CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH,
        CURLAUTH_BASIC);

    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type:application/json',
        'Authorization: apikey '
        .$apiKey
    );
    curl_setopt($ch,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
        $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,
        true);
    curl_setopt($ch,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,
        'POST');
    curl_setopt($ch,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,
        false);
    curl_setopt($ch,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
        $json);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch,
        CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Yes and that little part where you wrap the array in another array is what does the trick to get the square brackets :) (see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559735/no-square-bracket-json-array )

Comment: Trying to find your list's marketing permissions values in your MailChimp account? 

Use  the API to add a new subscriber or update one; the response will include the available permissions for your audience.

"marketing_permissions": [
        {
            "marketing_permission_id": "60c5898000",
            "text": "Email",
            "enabled": true
        },
        {
            "marketing_permission_id": "f816caf000",
            "text": "Direct Mail",
            "enabled": false
        },
    ]

Answer (score 0):

Five years later, the documentation about updating marketing permissions via the API (Mailchimp GDPR) is still very poor.

Thanks to the @mycaravam's post how to prepare the array, I was able to successfully update the marketing permissions like this:

```
// load API
require_once( [ PROJECT ROOT ] . '/vendor/autoload.php');

// create client
$mailchimp = new MailchimpMarketing\ApiClient();

// config client
$mailchimp->setConfig([
    'apiKey' => 'YOUR API KEY HERE',
    'server' => 'YOUR SERVER PREFIX HERE'
]);

// How to get the id: https://mailchimp.com/help/find-audience-id/
$list_id = 'YOUR AUDIENCE ID HERE';

// user email
$user_email = 'USER EMAIL HERE';

// opt-in IDs - create dummy subscription and see them in the response obj.
 
try {
   // setListMember will update the user if already exists, if not - it will add it.
   $response = $mailchimp->lists->setListMember( $list_id , $user_email, 
        [
            "email_address" => $user_email,
            "status_if_new" => "subscribed",
            "marketing_permissions" => array (
                   0  => array(                                                                                              
                          'marketing_permission_id' => 'OPT-IN 1 ID',
                          'enabled' => true,                                                                                         
                              ),                                                                                 
                   1  => array(
                          'marketing_permission_id' => 'OPT-IN 2 ID',                                                                                                    
                          'enabled' => true,                                                                                             
                              )                                                                              
             )
        ]);
    }
    catch (MailchimpMarketing\ApiException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```