# Message formatting in Slack in using blocks layout

Tags: php, json, slack-api

I want to send message to my slack app using the blocks layout format. I create an associative array in PHP and then use json_encode() to convert it to JSON. The problem is that it is not converted into the JSON format slack is expecting and I get an error 'invalid blocks format'. Here is my code, the output and the output expected by slack.

```
$data = array(
    'blocks' => array(
        'type' => 'mrkdwn',
        'text' => 'Danny Torrence left the following review for your property'
    ),
);
$data = json_encode($data);
```

I get the following output:

```
{"blocks":{"type":"mrkdwn","text":"Danny Torrence left the following review for your property"}}
```

However, Slack is expecting the JSON in the following format:

```
{"blocks":["type":"mrkdwn","text":"Danny Torrence left the following review for your property"]}
```

I just need to convert one '{' to '[' and one '}' to ']' in the end. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation, but I believe this is a duplicate of: [no square bracket json array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559735/no-square-bracket-json-array)

Also, this is not valid json, you can check on https://jsonlint.com/?code=

```
{"blocks":["type":"mrkdwn","text":"Danny Torrence left the following review for your property"]}
```

To summarize the post, all you really need to do is wrap your inner array with another array

```
$data = array(
    'blocks' => array(array(
        'type' => 'mrkdwn',
        'text' => 'Danny Torrence left the following review for your property'
    )),
);
```

this returns:

```
{"blocks":[{"type":"mrkdwn","text":"Danny Torrence left the following review for your property"}]}
```

Comment: Indeed. The reason the API wants an array of layout blocks is, because you can have more than one block in your message